# HTML stop marquee tag

Tags: html, css, marquee

I wanted to know if there is a way of stopping the flow of images in marquee tag of html using only HTML/CSS.

```
<marquee><a href="#" style="font-size:24px"><img src="hp.jpg" width="134" height="202" style="float:left;padding-right:10px;" alt=""></a></marquee>
```

Several linked images like these are in between the marquee tags and I wanted to stop their flow preferably on mouse hover. If you think it's possible please tell me the solution.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `<marquee>` is obsolete: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee.

Comment: Stop using obsolete HTML (`<marquee>`) and start using something a bit more up to date, like CSS animations. Then you can easily alter it via `:hover`

Comment: No, not only with HTML

Comment: I know, I would but this is a non-IT project for a friend and they haven't been taught this advanced CSS so they can't use it, they have to strictly stick to what they have been taught and implement them. So, if you think there's any workaround for this then it would be very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

> [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/C4Y2B/6/)

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();"><img src="hp.jpg" width="134" height="202" style="float:left;padding-right:10px;" alt="llsdasdada"></marquee>
```

Comment: Actually I've had this solution for quite a while and I was always trying it in Firefox and it never worked and just by luck today I tried it in Chrome and it worked.. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<marquee onmouseover="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 0, 0);" onmouseout="this.setAttribute('scrollamount', 6, 0);">
your text here
</marquee>
```

Answer (score -2):

try this!

Press Button

Firstly i have used marquee tag and then used buttons to start
and stop the flow.

Comment: Hello! Please complete your answer so it can help other people!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).